# Unable to execute SendMessage()?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

When I am executing:

```
SendMessage(hMsgBox, WM_COMMAND, IDOK, NULL)
```

It is always going to ANSI and telling an error:

```
error C2660: 'SendMessageA' : function does not take 4 parameters.
```

Why it is not taking UNICODE?

this is my actual code

```
MessageBox("Plsease wait..","Wait",0);



        HWND hMsgBox = NULL;
        hMsgBox = (HWND)FindWindow("#32270", "Wait");
        if (hMsgBox != NULL)
        {
             SendMessage(hMsgBox, WM_COMMAND, IDOK, NULL);
        }
```

Comment: Are u including Winuser.h? Can u share the simple code to reproduce this error?

Comment: This just displays a message box before trying to restart the print spool service, rather than displaying a message box *while* restarting the print spool service.

Comment: @ta.speot.is your answer is not matching OP's question.

Comment: @goths It's not an answer. I'm pointing out that the code won't work. [`CWnd::MessageBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0eebkf6f.aspx) is synchronous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must prefix SendMessage with :: like below so that the current class's (CWnd) SendMessage is not called.

```
::SendMessage(hMsgBox, WM_COMMAND, IDOK, NULL);
```

Plus you must define UNICODE preprocessor flag in your compiler option so that it takes the unicode version.

Comment: +1 But there's no point in doing this, `MessageBox` executes synchronously and by the time we get to `FindWindow(..., "Wait")` it's already closed.

Comment: The question doesn't match with multiple doubts you are having. Based on your code it looks like you must use multi threading. Or at least you must use a mode less dialog here.

Comment: there is any other way to do this but exactly i want the same.